# Dynamic Bootstrap Well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a template that gets all of the information generated from an external program. I am attempting to make this template a bit more modern and less 1992.

The page used to work with a table. It didn't look very nice so I am attempting to remove the table and just have everything on the screen fluid.

For the containers of the text I have used the bootstrap `well` class. The problem is that if one well is a bit longer then the other, it looks very odd. I need both of the `<div class="well">` to be the height if the tallest one.

I have tried to do this with a lot of different CSS. I really don't want to have to go back to a table.

The code is below.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        Info                             
    <br>
        <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        Info                             
    <br>
        <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this on live site?.. if so, can you post the link?

Comment: Not a live site, sorry.

Comment: atleast create fiddle or something.

Comment: I hope this is what you were after, not sure how it helps, but I hopefully it does. https://jsfiddle.net/x3ehq57g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what you want is that the `div's` height must equal to the div that has a lot of data...

try using jquery.

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".well").map(function ()
{
   return $(this).outerHeight();
}).get());

$('.well').height(maxHeight);
```

check this out:
https://jsfiddle.net/x3ehq57g/2/